# NullReferenceException adding to list in parent class

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance

I am working on an application to add users to groups in Active Directory, with two classes: ADUser and Student, which inherits from ADUser.

```
public class ADUser
    property UserID as string
    property MemberOf as new List(Of String)
    (etc)
end class

public class Student inherits ADUser
    property subjects as new list(Of Subject) 'Subject is a class of multiple strings
end class
```

I am attempting to copy the subject name from the subjects list to the MemberOf list, which results in a NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). The following code generates an error on the me.MemberOf.Add line:

```
        Function ConvertSubjectsToGroupMembership() As Boolean
        Try
            For Each s As Subject In Subjects
                Me.MemberOf.Add(String.Format("t.{0}", s.ShortName).ToString)
            Next
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

My understanding of inheritance is that the MemberOf list should be created when the Student object is created, however this does not seem to be the case.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit:
I managed to work around the issue by modifying the function to create a list(of String), which is then copied to the MemberOf property:

```
    Function ConvertSubjectsToGroupMembership() As Boolean
    Dim SubjectShortNameList As New List(Of String)

    For Each s As Subject In Subjects
        SubjectShortNameList.Add(String.Format("t.{0}", s.ShortName).ToString)
    Next

    Try
        MemberOf = SubjectShortNameList
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

It works, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it. I look forward to reading the answers/opinions of others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are nulling out MemberOf somewhere else in code. Assuming ConvertSubjectsToGroupMembership is a function on Student I ran the code and it worked fine. You could try expanding the property so you can set a breakpoint. This will allow you to find out where the Null is being introduced.

```
Public Class ADUser
    Property UserID As String
    Private _MemberOf As New List(Of String)
    Public Property MemberOF As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _MemberOf
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            _MemberOf = value ***'breakpoint here***
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: That's exactly what happened. When I stepped through the code I remembered that a constructor had been set up which set the `MemberOf` property to nothing, causing the list to be nulled. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.